# image preview tooltip and wait until mouse leaves the tooltip

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip, mouseover

I've been searching google and they have tooltips but I'm trying to look for something where I can hover an image and a larger version of the image will popup like a tooltip, but I would like to zoom in place of where the image is and also have content in it, and not have the tooltip disappear until my mouse rolls out of the tooltip block. A lot of tooltips will disappear when you roll out of the image you're hovering. I'm trying to keep the tooltip there until the mouse rolls out of the popup.

Any ideas where I can start looking or tutorials on it?

Thanks! appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TipTip plugin:
http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: this does look very nice, but it looks like they use the title attribute, but for my scenario I need to build div boxes because i would need to insert various content and not just a title

Comment: This doesn't work only with title, you can put any html you want inside the tooltip. Check the link, cheers

Answer (score 0):

A tooltip is probably not what you want, but there are a lot of [image zoom plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html) you can check out. To me it sounds like you are describing jQZoom from that list.

Comment: Not exactly, I'm trying to have a tooltip div box popup and stay active until the mouse moves out of the box.